# How do I strip dollar signs ($) from data/ escape special characters in R?

Tags: r, escaping

I've been using `gsub("toreplace","replacement", myvector)` to clean out data in R. While this works for commas and the like, removing `"$"` has no effect. So if I do `gsub("$","",myvector)` all the dollar signs remain in place.

I think this is because `$` is a special character in R. I tried escaping it `"\$"` but that yields the same result (no effect). And I couldn't find a resource on escaping special characters in R.

Obviously I should do this in preprocessing. But I was wondering if anyone out there knew how to either a) escape special characters in R b) get rid of pesky `$` in R directly. For science.

Answer (score 30):

You have to escape it twice, first for R, second for the regex.

```
gsub('\\$', '', c("a$a", "bb$"))
[1] "aa" "bb"
```

See `?Quotes` for details on quoting and escaping.

Answer (score 21):

Use `fixed = TRUE`:

```
gsub('$', '', c("a$a", "bb$"), fixed = TRUE)
```

Then you don't need to worry about any special characters.  In `stringr`, this is implemented a little differently:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(c("$100","ta$ty"), fixed("$"), "")
```

Thanks to DiggyF and James for the examples!

Answer (score 14):

Escaping characters can be a pain some times, but just putting it in square brackets (make it a character class) helps with this:

```
> gsub("[$]","",c("$100","ta$ty"))
[1] "100"  "taty"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have $ followed by number in  set of data columns (e.g. $400,000) there is an easier way that worked like charm for me. 
data%>% 
  mutate_at(5:6, parse_number) 
where 5:6 are the data column numbers.