# Removing Two Characters From A String

Tags: r, stringr

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639713/how-do-i-strip-dollar-signs-from-data-escape-special-characters-in-r).

So I have a character vector with currency values that contain both dollar signs and commas. However, I want to try and remove both the commas and dollar signs in the same step.

This removes dollar signs =

```
d = c("$0.00", "$10,598.90", "$13,082.47")
gsub('\\$', '', d)
```

This removes commas =

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(c("10,0","tat,y"), fixed(c(","), "")
```

I'm wondering if I could remove both characters in one step.

I realize that I could just save the gsub results into a new variable, and then reapply that (or another function) on that variable. But I guess I'm wondering about a single step to do both.

Comment: I'm no regex expert, but maybe `gsub('\\$|,', '', d)`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since answering in the comments is bad:

```
gsub('\\$|,', '', d)
```

replaces either `$` or (`|`) `,` with an empty string.

Comment: what are the double back slash for?@joran

Comment: @WhiteBig `$` is a special character in regexes and so much be escaped. You can read about it via `?regex`.

Comment: @WhiteBig Kind of. It's just that \ is itself a special character, so it too needs to be escaped. So you escape the `$`: `\$`, but then \ needs to be escaped as well, so you end up with `\\$`.

Comment: got you, can we put single back slash before $ and , separately?

Comment: @WhiteBig No. The `$` must have two, and the `,` doesn't need any (not a special character).

Answer (score 4):

take a look at `?regexp` for additional special regex notation:

```
> gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', d)
[1] "000"     "1059890" "1308247"
```

Comment: I think that will strip the decimal point as well, which seems to not be what the OP wanted. @joran's answer above seems to do it exactly without over-reaching.

Comment: @thelatemail you're correct!  I shouldn't answer questions when there is tequila around!  the answer  joran provided is much better.